# How to set log level with structlog when not using event parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, structlog

The idiomatic way (I think) to create a logger in structlog that only prints up to a certain log level is to use the following:

```
        wrapper_class=structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger(logging.INFO),
```

This works fine, but it breaks with the following pattern:

```
                l = logger.bind(event="get_tar", key=value)
                l.info(status="download_start")
                buf = f.read()
                l.info(status="download_finish")
```

by default, when using the `logfmt` format -- structlog will print the "message" as the `event` key, so I just like to set it directly.

Anyways, this breaks though b/c under the hood `make_filtering_bound_logger` calls this:

```
    def make_method(level: int) -> Callable[..., Any]:
        if level < min_level:
            return _nop

        name = _LEVEL_TO_NAME[level]

        def meth(self: Any, event: str, **kw: Any) -> Any:
            return self._proxy_to_logger(name, event, **kw)

        meth.__name__ = name

        return meth
```

which *requires* an event kwarg to exist. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event` is the only (reasonable :)) key that cannot be bound – it’s always the log message. That’s not a matter of `make_…` but all structlog internals.

You *can* get something similar-ish by renaming a key-value pair using the [EventRenamer](https://www.structlog.org/en/latest/api.html#structlog.processors.EventRenamer) processor.

See also https://github.com/hynek/structlog/issues/35

It’s good you brought this up, I’m currently rewriting the docs and am looking for common recipes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought it might be possible to bind `event` because that works with the basic `structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger`

Comment: Is there a way  can set the log level by using a `BoundLogger`?

Comment: Unless you use standard library integration, there is no concept of a log level. However: the processors get the name of the logging method passed as the second argument, so you can work with that.